# Modify Sign Up Path Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to redirect a user to a specific page based on where they sign up within my application. For example, if you sign up from /users/sign_up you'll be directed to the homepage, but if you sign up from a sign up form from /users/1 then I want to redirect you back to that user's profile after you sign up. Is this possible with Devise?

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: please carefully read documentation there is described in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do as bellow :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :remember_my_last_path

  def after_sign_up_path_for resource
    if cookies[:last_path].blank?
      super
    else
      cookies[:last_path]
    end
  end

  private 
  def remember_my_last_path
    cookies[:last_path] = request.fullpath
  end

end
```

In this way you set hash value last_path to your cookies and call this in every controller. When you click on register, you call devise method after_sign_up method which you overrided,  and then you send user to specific path or to default path .

Hope this will help you  .